# Xcopy and hosts file in windows scheduled tasks

Tags: scheduled-task, hosts-file, xcopy

I have some trouble with xcopy or maybe with `windows/drivers/etc/hosts` DNS file.
If I add my xcopy command in a windows scheduled task, xcopy can not resolve server's name stored in hosts file, infact, if I change the command with ip address instead of names everything works..
can you tell me why?

This is the hosts file:

```
10.1.1.200  diskstation
10.1.1.201  rackstation
```

This is the not working command:

```
xcopy \\diskstation\bck\VHD \\rackstation\backup\vhd /e /y /I
```

This is the working command:

```
xcopy \\10.1.1.200\bck\VHD \\rackstation\backup\vhd /e /y /I
```

NB: the first command works if i run it from console, my trouble is only when it is call by scheduled task.
NB2: a "ping diskstation" test is successful

Comment: Please post the (not-working) xcopy command AND the line from the hosts file specifying that host. One of them must have a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run the xcopy from a .bat file and run the bat file from Task Schedueler but as Tonny said above , copy/paste the command and let us know how do you run it .